# align list item text vertically

Tags: html, css

Is there a simple way to make the list items that take up two lines to align vertically with the text above? Thanks

```
* Cats            
* Turtles
* Frogs
* Horses and 
Zebras           
* Dogs
* Tigers and
Leopards
```

I want it to look like this

```
* Cats            
* Turtles
* Frogs
* Horses and 
  Zebras           
* Dogs
* Tigers and
  Leopards
```

Comment: Simple way is to add `padding-left` on some elements. Could you post your html code?

Comment: Why mot just use `<ul><li>`> Then on the lines that have more than one entry add a `<br/>` after the word **and**. I know that is not optimal and may not be what you want, but it is a simple solution and may be enough to get your code working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use the `list-style-position` property.  I limited the width of the list to show the behaviour if there is overflow by adding the `<div class="surround">`, but it is for effect only. Read more on lists here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp

```css
ul {
  list-style-position:outside;
}
.surround {
  width:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="surround">
  <ul>
    <li>Cats</li>
    <li>Turtles</li>
    <li>Frogs</li>
    <li>Horses and Zebras</li>
    <li>Dogs</li>
    <li>Tigers and Leopards</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks...I had my list-style-position set to inside which was causing the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Using basic HTML list tags (`<ul>` and `<li>`) with a `max-width` CSS setting will let you do that.  See this example:

```css
li {
  max-width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Cats</li>
  <li>Turtles</li>
  <li>Frogs</li>
  <li>Horses and Zebras</li>
  <li>Dogs</li>
  <li>Tigers and Leopards</li>
</ul>
```